# QuickBook Autoload Integration with codeigniter (Fatal error: Class 'DataService' not found)

Tags: codeigniter, quickbooks

I am facing prob to integrate Quickbook with codeigniter.

I installed the Quick book with following commands

```
$ composer require quickbooks/v3-php-sdk
$ composer update
```

but when I call that from controller it returns an error

```
$configpath =  '../vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/sdk.config';
$dataService = DataService::Configure($configpath);
```

Comment: Post the rest of your code. Post the actual error message.

Comment: function index() 
    {
       $dataService = DataService::Configure("vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/sdk.config");

       print_r($dataService);die;
    }

Comment: this is the controller function and i load the autoload file then call the dataservice function it said undefine

Comment: Have you set composer path in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` as `$config['composer_autoload'] = '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';` or `$config['composer_autoload'] = true;` if vendor directory is child of application directory?

Comment: it works for me thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

On the start of your php script, add 
`use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;`